# Моя реализация односвязного списка(потомок Queue). Что можно оптимизировать?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода, односвязный-список

Вот она:

```
public class UnidirectionalQueue<T> implements Queue<T>{

    private Element first;

    private Element last;

    int modCount;

    private int size;

    public UnidirectionalQueue(){
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }

    public UnidirectionalQueue(Collection<T> collection){
        addAll(collection);
    }

    private class Element{
        Element next;
        T value;

        Element(T value){
            this.value = value;
            next = null;
        }

        public void setValue(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void setNext(Element next){
            this.next = next;
        }

        public T getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public Element getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return next != null;
        }

        public void deleteNextLink() {
            next = null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        if(size == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for(Element current = first;; current = current.getNext()) {
            if(current.getValue().equals(o)) {
                return true;
            }
            if(!current.hasNext()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Itr();
    }

    private class Itr implements Iterator<T>{
        Element elementNow;
        boolean isFirstTime;

        {
            elementNow = first;
            isFirstTime = true;
        }

        Itr(){}

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return elementNow != null && (elementNow.hasNext() || isFirstTime);
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if(isFirstTime) {
                isFirstTime = false;
                return elementNow.getValue();
            }
            elementNow = elementNow.getNext();
            return elementNow.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            UnidirectionalQueue.this.remove(UnidirectionalQueue.this.getLinkBeforeForRemoveForLink(elementNow), elementNow);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        Object[] array = new Object[size];
        int index = 0;
        for(Element current = first;; current = current.getNext(), index++) {
            array[index] = current.getValue();
            if(!current.hasNext()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <E> E[] toArray(E[] a) {
        T[] elementData = (T[]) toArray();
        //copy past from ArrayList class
        if (a.length < size)
            // Make a new array of a's runtime type, but my contents:
            return (E[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
        System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
        if (a.length > size)
            a[size] = null;
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        modCount++;

        if(size == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for(Element before = null, current = first;; before = current, current = current.getNext()) {
            if(current.getValue().equals(o)) {
                remove(before, current);
                return true;
            }
            if(!current.hasNext()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private Element getLinkBeforeForRemoveForLink(Object o) {
        if(size == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        for(Element before = null, current = first;; before = current, current = current.getNext()) {
            if(current == o) {
                return before;
            }
            if(!current.hasNext()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    //XXX
    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        if(c.size() == 0) { // can delete
            return false;
        }
        if(size == 0 || size < c.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        for(Object value : c) {
            if(!contains(value)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    //XXX
    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        modCount++;

        if(c.size() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for(T value : c) {
            add(value); // optimize
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        modCount++;

        if(c.size() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if(size == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        for(Element before = null, current = first;; before = current, current = current.getNext()) {
            for(Object o : c) {
                if(current.getValue().equals(o)) {
                    current = remove(before, current);
                }
            }
            if(!current.hasNext()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        modCount++;

        if(c.size() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if(size == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        out:
        for(Element before = null, current = first;; before = current, current = current.getNext()) {
            for(Object o : c) {
                if(current.getValue().equals(o)) {
                    if(!current.hasNext()) {
                        break out;
                    }
                    continue out;
                }
            }
            current = remove(before, current);

            if(!current.hasNext()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private Element remove(Element before, Element current) {
        if(current == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        size--;
        Element next = current.getNext();
        if(next == null) { // ?on
            if(before == null) { // non
                first = null;
                last = null;
                return null;
            } else { // oon
                before.deleteNextLink();
                last = before;
                return last;
            }
        } else { // ?oo
            if(before == null) { // noo
                first = next;
                return first;
            } else { // ooo
                before.setNext(next);
                return before;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        modCount++;

        first = null;
        last = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T e) {
        modCount++;


        if(size == 0) {
            first = new Element(e);
            last = first;

            size++;
            return true;
        }

        last.setNext(new Element(e));
        last = last.getNext();

        size++;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(T e) {
        return add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public T remove() {
        modCount++;

        if(size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        Element toRemove = first;
        first = first.getNext();
        if(first == null) {
            last = null;
        }

        size--;

        return toRemove.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public T poll() {
        modCount++;

        if(size == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        Element toRemove = first;
        first = first.getNext();
        if(first == null) {
            last = null;
        }

        size--;

        return toRemove.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public T element() {
        if(size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        return first.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public T peek() {
        if(size == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        return first.getValue();
    }

}
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это вообще не вопрос.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ну, инспекция-кода же. Спрашивал, сказали - можно. Когда я человека на CodeReview послал.

Comment: Если вам нужно, чтобы кто-нибудь сделал ревью вашего кода и дал рекомендации, то отредактируйте вопрос и напишите об этом. Кнопка "Задать **вопрос**" так называется потому, что в результате её нажатия на SO должен появится именно вопрос.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Метки недостаточно? Тогда, конечно, изменю